# Connecting to a PSQL dockerized DB from host

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I've got some trouble configuring a PostgreSQL database in a Docker container. My main issue is I want to access it from my host directly.

My container configuration looks like:

```yml
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10.4
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./var/docker/db/pg_hba.conf:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

My `pg_hba.conf` file is the default one, with two extra added lines:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust

# IPv4 local connections:

########### LINE ADDED ###########
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

# IPv6 local connections:

########### LINE ADDED ###########
host    all             all             ::/0                    md5

host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust

# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

When I'm trying to connect to my container, I'm facing the following error:

```
psql --host=127.0.0.1

psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I first checked that ports are correctly redirected on my Docker container:

```
docker ps

IMAGE               COMMAND                         STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
postgres:10.4       "docker-entrypoint.s…"          Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   db_1
```

Then, I checked that PSQL is correctly running, executing the following in the container:

```
netstat -tlnp

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:42293        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

From what I'm understanding:

- Server listens to all requests made on port 5432, from all hosts.
- Container forwards all traffic on host port 5432 to container port 5432,
- PSQL asks a password for all non local hosts (the two lines I've addded in `pg_hba.conf`)

What am I missing? Is there any other thing I can check to debug my issue?

Comment: Can you get a TCP connection with telnet? Run `telnet localhost 5432` and see if it connects.

Comment: Looks like I can: 

Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: Okay, this is a weird case... It is not a network issue, as you can establish a TCP connection. Maybe there is another application listening on that port? Run `ss -tulpen | grep 5432` and see it the line has `users:(("dockerd"`.

Comment: I have a "* : 5432" listening on TCP, with * : * peer. Not sure to understand the process yet: "ino:959086 sk:1c v6only:0 <->". Is it normal?

Comment: I may have noticed something yet: I'm mounting the `pg_hba.conf` in the same place of my `pg_data` volume. Trying to investigate on this part.

Comment: You need to run it with `sudo`, sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: My bad: I'm not familiar at all with this command. Looks less cryptic now: it has a `users:(("docker-proxy"` part.  So I guess it's good?

Comment: I think the place to mount the `pg_hba.conf` is correct, but I do not know if it is a problem to mount it into an already mounted directory. When I run DBs in docker, I do not use docker volumes for the data directory, but mount a host path there. If you do that, you can directly edit the file. -- As for the "docker-proxy" user, that seems to be correct, so the correct application is listening on that port.

Comment: Good idea: I removed the mounted volume to edit configuration files directly within my IDE. Trying to find the parameter(s) causing the issue. What a productive day! :p

Comment: Maybe `docker logs` or the postgres log will tell you more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223032/discussion-between-jonathan-petitcolas-and-toydarian).

Answer (score 0):

Well... That's one of the embarassing dev moment... After investigating it further with @toydarian (huge thanks for your time!), I finally noticed it was due to an alias I've set a long time ago:

> alias psql="docker run -ti --rm postgres:10.4 psql"

It explains why it didn't work. Let's see the bright side: I've learnt a lot about PSQL configuration! :)

Comment: Oh wow! That explains it... :D Glad you figured it out! :)